# Who modified my Evernote dates

Tags: evernote

I use en fairly regularly and have a few apps/sites that I have authorized to contribute to my en account. I almost always sort by modified date so that my most recently changed notes are at the top. Periodically (once every week or 2?) I get several notes (10 +/-) notes that I have not touched in weeks or even months or years getting marked as modified "today" so that they fill up the top of my en list of notes.

I recognize that this is not the end of the world, but I want to figure out who/how the notes are being changed. Is it one of my apps/sites or does en sometimes do this itself? Any idea how I can see who changed a note? Ever seen this type of behavior before?

I primarily access en on my android phone but also on my win 10 desktop periodically and very rarely using the Web interface.

Comment: Contact Evernotes and ask them what conditions outside of editing the notes would result in the data modified being update.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting evernote it seems there was some problem between my android wear evernote app and my phone evernote app. I don't use evernote on my watch (just put the app out of curiosity) so I just uninstalled it and I haven't had any problems since - fingers crossed... :-)